Visual Studio cannot output Unicode Characters
I've made a program for school; that goes through a plain text file and makes a concordance for each word. It will take each word, remove non-alphabetical characters from the front and back, and put it into a Binary Search Tree. When encountering Unicode characters in a text, you get random ascii characters that make up the multibyte character instead of what it is: for example, "yarns—and," is outputted as "yarnsùand." I spent hours months ago and this week trying to solve this problem, so what do I do?
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38242/Reading-UTF-8-with-C-streams#mozTocId353176 This article seemed useful. But not being able to read in utf-8 is a solved problem, so making up a facet didn't seem useful. I didn't try it though because of that. Using imbue(utf8_locale/utf16_locale) does not help nor does imbuing wsstream with codecvvt,
Here is a MRE of the bug.
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <windows.h>
#include <consoleapi2.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    wfstream file;
    file.open("Example.txt", ios::in);
    // Changes buffer from char to wchar_t
    wchar_t* buffer = new wchar_t[100];
    file.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buffer, 100);
    wchar_t CurrentStreamCharacter = file.get();
    wstring NewWord = L"";
    while (file) 
    {
        NewWord.push_back(CurrentStreamCharacter);
        CurrentStreamCharacter = file.get();
    }
    //SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
    wcout << NewWord << endl;
    wcout << "yarns—and even convictions. The Lawyer—the best of old fellows—had,";
    return 0;
}

Here is the text in Example.txt.
yarns—and even convictions. The Lawyer—the best of old fellows—had,


You could use mbstowcs to convert everything into wchars first.

What encoding is the file using? What are your locale settings? What code page is your terminal using?

Two things needed to fix your wcout, add _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT);  to enable unicode characters to the console output,  and your string should be wcout << L"yarns—and" Note the added L before your string.

@user20716902
wcout << L"yarns—and even convictions. The Lawyer—the best of old fellows—had,"
just leads to the final string being, "yarns," and nothing else.  Also,  _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT) leads to this error, "error C2065: '_O_U8TEXT': undeclared identifier ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed."

"I've made a program for school" -- That's nice, but not the most important piece of information for your question (the first sentence implies most important). At best, it should be a note at the end of your question for context. It looks like your question actually is about Reading Unicode characters from a file. (Or maybe it involves output? Did you compare the characters from the file to the characters in your hard-coded string?)

What compiler?  What are your compiler flags?  What is your file encoding?  Why are you using 65001 if you are using wcout?

@Elijay That was a commented out piece of code. My file encoding is utf-8. My compiler is whatever Visual Studio code uses.

@TheGuradian you need to imbue() a UTF-8 locale into the wfstream in order to read a UTF-8 file with it. Also, you should use wifstream instead of wfstream. Otherwise, use (i)fstream instead to read into a char string first, and then use a Unicode API/library to decode the UTF-8 into a wchar_t string.

You have "Visual Studio" in the title and in one of the tags, but you say "whatever Visual Studio code uses" in your comment. So, which one do you really use: Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code? And what version?

@RemyLebeau I did setlocale(LC_ALL, "") though.

@heapunderrun I meant Visual Studio now I cannot edit the comment.

@TheGuradian the code you showed does not use setlocale(), and in any case it has no effect on wfstream. Have a look at Read Unicode UTF-8 file into wstring

Your title "Visual Studio cannot output Unicode Characters" - Is blatantly false.

...I have a answer to this question now...this site was no help...please let me answer it.
